# Why does var combined = null + "" has a value?

Tags: javascript

Probably a very basic question from a confused javascript noob...

Why do

```
var hasthisvalue = null;
if (hasthisvalue)
    print("hasthisvalue hs value");
```

and

```
var hasthatvalue = "";
if (hasthatvalue)
    print("hasthatvalue has value");
```

don't print anything, but if I combine these two

```
var combined = "hasthisvalue" + "hasthatvalue";
if (combined)
    print ("combined has value");
```

it does?

Or more directly:

```
var combined = null + "";
if (combined)
    print ("combined has value");
```

Why does "combined" has a value if I only add two variables that don't have values? What am I missing?

Comment: Because a non-empty string is a true-ish value. `null + ""` is the string `"null"`.

Comment: Second one, your conversion. First one, I think you meant something different.

Comment: In the first case you are concatenating 2 strings, not the variables.

Comment: @wong, I think that goal might be why he's asking the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compare them separately, each converts to `false` in the `if` check.  When you combine them, the `null` becomes the string `"null"`, so their concatenation is the string `"null"`, which does not convert to `false`

Answer (score 2):

The first 2 examples are situations where the values are *"falsy"*. These values are equal to `false` during a *loose comparison*:

- null
- undefined
- blank string
- boolean false
- the number 0
- NaN

Other values not in this list are *"truthy"* and are equal to `true` on a *loose comparison*.

The third case, you can try in the console. `null+''` becomes a string: `"null"` and is therefore truthy.